# How to append value for existing key in dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

The below code tries to store multiple values for a single key. I have managed to store the value for non-exist key. Can you guid me on how I can append value for existing key?

```
Dictionary<string,HashSet<string>> container = new Dictionary<string,HashSet<string>>();

foreach(dynamic x in records)
{  if(!container.ContainsKey(x.code))
   {
     HashSet<string> item = new HashSet<string>();
     item.Add(x.name);
     container.Add(x.code,item);
   }
}
```

Comment: Not that you specifically mentioned multi-threading, but it is worth calling out that this is not thread-safe.

Comment: Do you want only unique x.name ?

Comment: By the way, you can probably do the same with `records.GroupBy(r => r.code, r => r.name)`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for?

```
        Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> container = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
        HashSet<string> item;

        if (!container.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            item = new HashSet<string>();
            container.Add("key1", item);
        }
        else
        {
            item = container[s];
        }

        item.Add("value1");
```

Note that I'd expect if the dictionary doesn't have key `s` then you'll want to add the `HashSet<string>` with same key `s`, not `"key1"`, but that's up to you.

If indeed the key `s` should be added you can implement a reusable generic extension method:

```
    public static TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> newValueFactory)
    {
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
        {
            value = newValueFactory(key);
            dict.Add(key, value);
        }

        return value;
    }
```

then use it:

```
container.GetOrAdd(s, _ => new HashSet<string>()).Add("value1");
```